# How to set startIndex property in CountableRange<Int>

Tags: swift

Is there a way to allow modifying startIndex?

```
var range = 0..<array.count
range.startIndex = midIndex + 1
```

Cannot assign to property 'startIndex' is a get only property

Comment: `range = range.startIndex.advanced(by: 1)..<range.endIndex`

Comment: Thank, amazing example.